# Getting error while adding list elements to set

Tags: apex, list, set

Below is my code.names.add(newlist) gives error while names.addAll(newlist) gives error.While there is a method in apex where we can add list to a set and both should be of same datatype.

Apex class:

```
public class SetExample {
    public set<String> names{get;set;}
    public SetExample(){
        list<string> newlist = new list<string>();
        newlist.add('shashi');
        newlist.add('shashi');
        newlist.add('rakesh');
        newlist.add('rakesh');
        names = new set<string>();
        names.add('ram');
        names.add('sam');
        names.add('tam');
        names.add('uam');
        names.add('ram');
        names.add('ram');
        names.add('tam');
        names.add(newlist);
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure if it's a posting mistake, but you have `names.add(newlist);` where it should be `names.addAll(newlist);`

Comment: Would be much easier to help if you posted the error as well. For now the comment above is the only things I can see as well.

Comment: yes names.addAll(newlist); will work fine .I thought names.add(newlist); will also work but it gave error saying "Incompatible element type List<String> for collection of String".

Comment: Could any of you make a proper answer out of that ? :-)